# How do I create a new instance of a Structure in F#?

Tags: f#

I feel really dumb about this one, but I am having a real hard time finding documentation on this.

If I declare a struct like so:

```
type BuildNumber = 
    struct
        val major : int
        val minor : int
        val build : int
        val revision : int
    end
```

Then how do I make a new instance of the `BuildNumber` type?

Comment: Note that structs are rarely a good idea in F#, using a record is preferable.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! What makes a record better?

Comment: Structs are useful for the exact same thing in F# as they are in C# - keeping data on the stack for time-sensitive number crunching. However, some useful F# idioms and data structures can cause the data to unintentionally end up on the heap, and this type of low-level optimization is less-common in a high-level functional language like F#. Also, F# Records are nicer to work with, if you're not using a struct for performance reasons.

Comment: @EricDand: Records give you the same value-type semantics you'd expect from a stuct in C# (structural equality, immutability) and they are fully integrated in the language (so you have nice syntax for creating records and pattern matching on them). Whereas structs are a 'foreign' concept which is just cumbersome to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the `new` keyword and define a constructor for it.

For example:

```
type simple = 
    struct
        val A : int
        val B : int
        new (a: int, b: int) = { A = a; B = b; }
    end

let s = new simple(1, 2)
```

Comment: If there is no `new` in the definition, is it impossible to create an instance of the type? If so, is it useless?

Comment: @EricDand You can still do `new simple()` and it will work just fine. But all the fields will be the default value for the type (zero in this case) and immutable. So not 100% useless, but pretty close.

Comment: What's important to note if you are designing a struct type is that structs can always be zero-initialized (i.e. created with "parameterless constructor"), unlike ref types which are either null or must go through a real, declared constructor. So if you add methods to the struct, make sure you always handle the case where all fields are defaulted (this handling might be as simple as throwing an invalid op exception).

Comment: @latkin: "structs can always be zero-initialized": Almost... except if some of the fields are records or unions, or if some of the fields are classes or exceptions without the [<AllowNullLiteral>] attribute. In these cases, it is not possible to instantiate the struct _from F#_ with the default parameterless constructor. (But it can still be instantiated this way _from other .NET languages_.)

Comment: @MarcSigrist - that is not quite correct. F# does throw up some hurdles, but it's not hard to avoid them.  `Unchecked.defaultof<S>` or `(Array.zeroCreate<S> 1).[0]` do nicely. The point is that for ref types, stuff like that results in `null`, which as a class implementer you don't care about at all, either in C# or F# (members can't be invoked on nulls). For val types, *valid instances* come out, so as a struct implementer, your various members are expected to be able to operate in this situation.

Comment: @latkin: Thanks for further expanding on this. In a nutshell, the compile-time initialization checks on struct fields are only performed by the F# compiler when the default parameterless struct constructor is called _explicitly_. In this case, the compiler reports _error FS0688: The default, zero-initializing constructor of a struct type may only be used if all the fields of the struct type admit default initialization_. Otherwise, the compile-time checks are not performed. So, to be on the safe side, on has to implement custom runtime checks in the struct.

Comment: @EricDand marking the identifier as mutable will make it possible to set the values of the struct after creation (that might not have been the case in 16 but adding for someone reading post 22)